# How to open a page in Chrome from the command line, in a new tab or an existing tab as appropriate?

Tags: mac, command-line, google-chrome

I'm looking for a way to open a given page in Google Chrome from the command line, with the following behaviour:

- If the given page is already open in a tab, navigate to that tab
- If the given page is not already open in a tab, open the page in a new tab and show that tab

Currently when I open a URL from the command line (e.g. using "open http://godzillahaiku.tumblr.com" on Mac OS X), Chrome will always open the URL in a new tab. I end up with lots of duplicate tabs as a result, which is a minor annoyance.

I'm looking for a solution that works on Mac OS X, but a non-OS specific solution would be preferable.

I'd consider writing a Chrome extension for this if there's no existing solution.

Answer (score 24):

This is a simpler command line, but will still open a new tab:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome <file>
```

Comment: I get the error `'....\open' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Comment: This works for me on Mac OSX. Are you using a different OS?

Answer (score 7):

Turns out this can be done with a few lines of javascript in a Chrome extension.

Still open to other answers, but in the meantime I've written a Chrome extension to do this and put the source [online](http://github.com/mbhutton/chrome-duplicate-tab-detector).

Comment: Care to enlighten me what the downvote was for with some constructive criticism?

Comment: this little extension you made is in the pocket, thanks