# Command line usage for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, command-line-arguments, browser-tabs

Right now I have a command on Windows that invokes `chrome.exe` with a local (on disk) `.html` file as argument.

The resulting behaviour is: Chrome opens a new tab with that page.

What I want is:

- if the page is not already open: open it in a new tab (current behaviour)
- if the page is already opened: switch to that tab (rather that creating a new tab). (if more tabs with that page are opened, it doesn't matter to which tab to switch (probably  the last accessed would be best, but doesn't matter that much))

I need a Windows solution (and probably I will need a Linux solution, too).

I have search a page listing [Chromium command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), but the list too large and I couldn't find anything.

[Another question](https://superuser.com/questions/119009/how-to-open-a-page-in-chrome-from-the-command-line-in-a-new-tab-or-an-existing) has an answer for Mac.